# Intuitive explanation as to why we need a Brownian integral to model a stock.

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, finance, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

When I was presented the simple Black-Scholes model I was presented with the simple difference equation

$$\frac{\Delta S_t}{S_t}=\mu \Delta t+\sigma\Delta B_t.$$

It was explained that the relative change in the stocks risky asset would consist of a drift term, and a random term($\Delta B_t$).

A more advanced model is the SDE:

$$\frac{d S_t}{S_t}=\mu(t,\omega)dt+\sigma(t,\omega)dB_t.$$

Here $\mu$, and $\sigma$ are progressively measurable processes, and $\sigma$, must of course be such that the Itô-integral is well-defined. **However, now that we have randomness in $\mu$, why do we still need the $d B_t$?**

Comment: Why not having a look here : https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/50167/why-is-brownian-motion-useful-in-finance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because there is also a filtration with respect to which $\mu$ and $\sigma$ are predictable.

Think of a discrete process
$$ \frac{S_{t+\Delta t} - S_t}{S_t} = \mu(t,\omega) + \sigma(t,\omega) \Delta B_t .$$
At time $t$, the quantities $\mu(t,\omega)$ and $\sigma(t,\omega)$ depend upon everything that is known at time $t$.  At time $t = 0$, they are random variables, but at time $t$ they are completely known.  All that is unknown is whether the stock will go up or down.

Comment: Thank you very much! But do we need them to be predictable, and do we know that they are predictable? Is it not enough that they are adapted?

Comment: Predicatable with respect to $\mathcal F_{t + \Delta t}$.  Adapted with respect to $\mathcal F_t$.

Comment: But in continuous time we have from wikipedia that the definition of a predictable process is one that is measurable with respect to the predictable sigma-algebra, and the predictable sigma algebra is defined as the sigma algebra generated by all left-continuous adapted processes. Do we need this for $\mu$, and $\sigma$ or does this hold for them?

Comment: I always use discrete time to get the intuition.  But yes, you want this for $\mu$ and $\sigma$.

Comment: Thank you, would you mind also explaining why progressively measurable(and hence adapted) would not be enough(in continuous time)?

Comment: Because then it really isn't a model for the stock market of the type we wish to consider.